# primeng style to not override in all the pages. p-dialog style to not override p-confirmdialog style

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I have primeng  and  like the attached screenshot.

[image]
[image]

As you can see both these primeng html tags has div class "p-dialog-mask p-component-overlay p-dialog-mask-scrollblocker" in common. I want a different overlay for the parent pages when the dialog opens up and a different one when the confirmdialog opens up. I tried below:

```
p-dialog, .p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay{
    background-color: #000;
}

p-confirmdialog, .p-confirmdialog-mask.p-component-overlay{
    background-color: #rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)!important;
}
```

This didnt work. I tried to use a different style with [styleClass] in p-confirmDialog tag but even that wouldnt work. Irrespective of what i give , it takes the css for p-dialog and not picking a different css for p-confirmdialog.

For now I have added class names like below:

```
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c45-0,  
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c45-1,
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c45-2,
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c30-0,
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c30-1,
.p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay.ng-tns-c30-2{
    background-color: #000;
}
```

This works but it isnt consistent in all the enviornments. When I move code to UAT the generated class names are different in the browser and I have to keep changing . Is there a way i can change the styles without touching the class names. I am expecting this to be handled in p-dialog and p-confirmdialog. Any suggestions please. Additionally I would add black to p-dialog only on main page and in the remaining pages it should take the default css.

Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it comes from **style isolation**

Try to add `:host ::ng-deep` on the classes you want to override.

I had to do it multiple times in my project using primeng.

For example

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-chips.p-component {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Here in your case, it would be

```css
:host ::ng-deep p-dialog, 
:host ::ng-deep .p-dialog-mask.p-component-overlay {
    background-color: #000;
}

:host ::ng-deep p-confirmdialog, 
:host ::ng-deep .p-confirmdialog-mask.p-component-overlay {
    background-color: #rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important;
}
```